# Como linkar paginas Word Press Criação de Temas

Tags: wordpress, temas

Estou começando a criar temas com wordpress, e não sei como fazer com que as paginas que eu crio no painel apareceram no meu tema através do menu, o menu eu consegui adicionar através de funções no functions.php e no header.php, mas as paginas que eu adicionei no menu através do painel não aparecem quando eu clico nelas pelo menu, acho que é porque não configurei a pages.php ou algo assim, não sei bem, comecei agora e não sei como o wordpress funciona se alguém poder me dar uma luz eu agradeço ;)

Answer (score 0):

No wordpress você deve criar um arquivo `pages.php` como página padrão, esse arquivo vai ser usado para renderizar todas as páginas que você criar no admin do wordpress. Se você precisar de um template exclusivo para alguma página é necessário adicionar um comentário `template name` no início do seu arquivo. Com esse comentário você consegue selecionar o modelo de página no admin.

```
<?php

 /**
  * Template name: Página de Contato
  */

 // Arquivo que vai renderizar a página de contato.
```